# Система контроля версий Bazaar, как удалить файл?

Tags: bazaar

Я сделал commit, добавив 300 Мбайт дампа базы данных. Сразу этого не заметил, и сделал еще один commit. Как можно убрать файлы дампа из системы контроля версий Bazaar? Трудно будет передать на Launchpad столь большой объём информации, к тому же не нужной для контроля.

Answer (score 1):

Можно удалить из контоля версий последний commit командой [uncommit](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/user-reference/uncommit-help.html).

Comment: Судя по ответу, мне следует создать новую ветку, очистив данные о предыдущих изменениях? Трудно тянуть branch на 80мб, когда весь проект не весит и 10кб.